# Keyup event handler shows slow performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

My example:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '[contenteditable=true]', function (e) {
        
    let _this = $(this), text = _this.text();

    if (text.length === 1) {
        let span = $('<span>').text(text);
        _this.html(span);
    }

    console.log(_this.html());

});
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

My problem: If I type some text (more than 1 character) with normal speed into the div, code works fine. But, when I try to type text with fast speed, no `<span>` tag was appended to the div.

How can I fix that?

Comment: It's not *speed*, it's the fact that when you're going fast, you have mulitple keydowns before your first keyup, which means the first keyup sees more than one character in the div. If you used `keypress`, you'd get the desired result (or `input`, as Zakaria points out -- `input` fires on paste as well, which may or may not be what you want).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `input` event instead it's more efficient when you trach user inputs, check example below :

```
$(document).on('input', '[contenteditable=true]', function (e) {
    //Your logic
});
```

Or also `keypress` as *[T.J. Crowder comment's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314838/keyup-event-is-working-slow-performance/42314854#comment-71783478)* says :

```
$(document).on('keypress', '[contenteditable=true]', function (e) {
    //Your logic
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).on('input', '[contenteditable=true]', function (e) {
        
    let _this = $(this), text = _this.text();

    if (text.length === 1) {
        let span = $('<span>').text(text);
        _this.html(span);
    }

    console.log(_this.html());

});
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```